# How to hide table column on submit inside a modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

On a user profile page I have a table where the headings are not on the top but on the left side, and descriptions are on the right.

When user clicks 'edit profile' a modal opens up.

In the modal I want to hide table columns or I guess in this case rows by selecting the checkboxes and then hitting the 'save changes' button. When 'save changes' is clicked their choices should also be saved and updated on their profile.

I also want a few of the checkboxes to already be checked when they visit their profile page for the first time after registering. And then they should be able to change it there after.

My code is not working and I tried everything I could find on hiding columns... I have been looking for days. Any help is much appreciated!

```
TABLE
<div class="row">
<table class="table table-responsive-sm" id="profileTable" id="table-pagination" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%" >
              <tbody>
                  <?php



          $sql = "SELECT `dancing_since`, `dancer_dob`, `school`, `school_code`,`teacher_name`, `class_location`, `date_enrolled`, `date_firstdance`, `first_dance_name`, `current_lvl` FROM `dancers` WHERE name = '$name' AND dancer_name = '$dancerName'";
          $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

          //if($res==FALSE){
          //die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
          //  }

          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
              echo '
              <tr>
              <th class="tcol1">Dancing Since:</th>
              <td class="tcol1">'.$row["dancing_since"].'</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <th class="tcol2">D.O.B:</th>
              <td class="tcol2">'.$row["dancer_dob"].'</td>
              </tr>


              <tr>
              <th class="tcol3">School:</th>
              <td class="tcol3">'.$row["school"].'</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <th class="tcol4">School Code:</th>
              <td class="tcol4">'.$row["school_code"].'</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <th class="tcol5">Teachers Name:</th>
              <td class="tcol5">'.$row["teacher_name"].'</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <th class="tcol6">Class Location:</th>
              <td class="tcol6">'.$row["class_location"].'</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <th class="tcol7">Date Enrolled:</th>
              <td class="tcol7">'.$row["date_enrolled"].'</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <th class="tcol8">First Feis</th>
              <td class="tcol8">'.$row["first_dance_name"].'</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <th class="tcol9">Date of First Feis:</th>
              <td class="tcol9">'.$row["date_firstdance"].'</td>
              </tr> 

              <tr>
              <th class="tcol10">Current Level:</th>
              <td class="tcol10">'.$row["current_lvl"].'</td>
              </tr> 
              ';  
    }

    ?>
</tbody>
```

MODAL

```
<!--POPUP MODAL FORM-->
                        <div class="formModal">
                            <div class="formModal text-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary editprofile-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-editprofile-modal-lg">Edit Profile</button>
                            </div>


                            <!-- Modal -->

                            <div class="modal fade bd-editprofile-modal-lg" id="editProfile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editProfile" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-success modal-lg" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <form id="updateForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="tcol" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                                            <div class="controls">

                                                <!--Modal cascading tabs-->
                                                <div class="modal-c-tabs">

                                                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-2 light-blue darken-3" role="tablist">
                                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                                            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel7" role="tab">Edit Profile Information</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                                            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel8" role="tab">Change visiblity</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>

                                                    <!-- Tab panels -->
                                                    <div class="tab-content">

                                                        <!--Panel 7-->
                                                        //some code for edit profile form



                                                        <!-- PANEL 8 -->

                                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel8" role="tabpanel">
                                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                                                    <div class="panel-8-heading text-center">
                                                                        <b>Select up to 10 abilities you would like to appear on your profile.</b>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <br>

                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="col1" class="hidecol" id="col_1" data-column="0"/> Dancing Since
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="col2" class="hidecol" id="col_2" checked="checked" data-column="1" /> D.O.B
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="col3" class="hidecol" id="col_3" data-column="2"/> School
                                                                        </div>      
                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="col4" class="hidecol" id="col_4" checked="checked" data-column="3"/>  School Code
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="col5" class="hidecol" id="col_5" checked="checked" data-column="4"/>  Teacher's Name
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="col6" class="hidecol" id="col_6" checked="checked" data-column="5"/> Class Location
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" name="col7" id="col_7" checked="checked" data-column="6"/> Date Enrolled
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" name="col8" id="col_8" data-column="7" /> First competition
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" name="col9" id="col_9" checked="checked" data-column="8"/> Date of First dance
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" name="col10" id="col_10" data-column="9"  /> Current Level
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <!-- PANEL 8 END -->
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <!-- MODAL FOOTER -->
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save" id="save">Save changes</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {


//modal checkbox


$('#profileTable tr td:nth-child(3)').hide();
});
```

**EDIT**

Below are images of the user table and the modal with checkboxes. I want to be able to hide the entire row. so if user deselect  location then on their profile they would no longer see "location: NJ"

**PROFILE TABLE**

[image: Profile Table]

**MODAL**
[image: Modal]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different approach:

1. you write a modal form where user selects the content he or she wants to be visible in the profile page.
2. submit that data to the server.
3. reload the page
4. when creating a new page, return only the data that the user has selected in the form (from settings), use filter (or a set of if conditions as this seems to be homework) to select the data your user wants to see.
5. return only the necessary data
6. render it. (You will not need to hide the data)

This approach has several benefits:

1. you avoid the complexity of hiding / showing data
2. you avoid displaying data that should not be displayed: user can still view hidden columns if they edit html, and that is a huge no-no in web development.
3. it is easier to add new data to the profile
4. you can easily save the user preferences as per your requirement

If you want to go a step further, you can try improving the above by writing ajax code to update the rows dynamically, without reloading the entire page.

Will not be giving any specific code examples as its a lengthy task, and also it looks like a class or homework task. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, this is not homework but a website i'm trying to build for a client. Wouldn't this affect my table in my database? I don't want to alter my database table because the information is pulled on multiple different pages.

Comment: for a client its even a bigger antipattern to be hiding the data with html. You can create an intermittent table to handle these settings, or handle this with the backend code. 

You dont want to update many tables for it, but instead, create an independent structure that controls what data you expose to the client. You might want to have a db stucture like `modal_setting <many to one> user`  or `user['modal_settings_json']` and use this data to control what is being rendered on the modal.

Comment: Anything that you hide with html is not hidden from someone who can open chrome/edge debug tools. That is a big security hole in any live system.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if this is only an extract of the code or a mistake, because I can’t find any `<table>` defined in the modal. And from your jquery code you need an element with id `profileTable`.

I suggest you to state what have you tried and what is not working. Also you can divide the problem in a smaller scale and to identify the root cause. E.g. try the hide/show mechanism outside the modal, or break down the jquery code (if `$('#profileTable tr td:nth-child(3)')` return nothing then `.hide()` would take no effect)

**Update 1**

I think you are trying to hide the table column(the vertical one). First, the table has 2 ids, `profileTable` and `table-pagination`. Remove either one so the table has exactly one id. Since `#` is a id selector, multiple id may mess up the css. Second, let's put "modal" aside. Browser has no knowledge about modal, it just know there are bunch of nested html elements with different styling. With or without modal, javascript should work the same way. It helps you to break down your through model and find the root cause easier.

I made a demo base on the snippet you provided. Two buttons at the bottom shows how to hide and show column.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMpRbq

**Update 2**

Understand the requirement and update the demo. Hide/show the row instead of column. The concept is almost the same, the different is to select tr instead of td. I only make 2 checkbox since they are all the same.

```js
$('#filter-panel').on('change', 'input', function(e) {
  var rowIndex = $(e.currentTarget).val();

  $('#profileTable tr:nth-child(' + rowIndex + ')').toggle();

});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <table class="table table-responsive-sm" id="profileTable" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="tcol1">Dancing Since:</th>
        <td class="tcol1">'.$row["dancing_since"].'</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="tcol2">D.O.B:</th>
        <td class="tcol2">'.$row["dancer_dob"].'</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="tcol3">School:</th>
        <td class="tcol3">'.$row["school"].'</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="tcol4">School Code:</th>
        <td class="tcol4">'.$row["school_code"].'</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="tcol5">Teachers Name:</th>
        <td class="tcol5">'.$row["teacher_name"].'</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="tcol6">Class Location:</th>
        <td class="tcol6">'.$row["class_location"].'</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="tcol7">Date Enrolled:</th>
        <td class="tcol7">'.$row["date_enrolled"].'</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="tcol8">First Feis</th>
        <td class="tcol8">'.$row["first_dance_name"].'</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="tcol9">Date of First Feis:</th>
        <td class="tcol9">'.$row["date_firstdance"].'</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="tcol10">Current Level:</th>
        <td class="tcol10">'.$row["current_lvl"].'</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br /><br />

  <div id="filter-panel">

    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1" checked/> dancing since
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="2" checked/> d.o.b

  </div>
```

Comment: This is what I came up with, but it is still not working

$('#3').change(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('#profileTable tr td:nth-child(3)').show();
else
    $('#profileTable tr td:nth-child(3)').hide();
      }).change();

Also, where would I define the table in my modal?

Comment: i dont know how would your page finally look like. but since you have your css selector #profileTable, i assume there is a element like <table id="profileTable">. however, i cant it from the material you provided

Comment: Oh, it was a mistake I forgot to indent 4 times in the beginning but it is updated now. But the code I tried is not working.

Comment: Your codepen only hides the second column which is the descriptions. But I want to hide rows. So I want to hide both the heading and the row with a check box.

I basically want the column visibility like in datatables example found here https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/simple.html

but I want it to hide horizontally not vertically. I want the users to be able to choose what they want to show on their profile page, so after clicking on a checkbox and then clicking the save changes button even after refreshing the page their selection should remain.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
    <table border="1" id="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr id='trow1'>
                <th>Dancing Since:</th>
                <td>2012</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='trow2'>
                <th>D.O.B:</th>
                <td>1994</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='trow3'>
                <th>School:</th>
                <td>ABC</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='trow4'>
                <th>School Code:</th>
                <td>1001</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='trow5'>
                <th>Teachers Name:</th>
                <td>Badai</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="myBtn_colSwitch" style="margin-left: 2%;" onClick="columnSwitchMODAL()">Row Filter</button> <!-- onclick opens MODAL -->
    <!-- The Modal Column Switch -->
            <div id="myModal_colSwitch" class="modal_colSwitch">
                    <div class="modal-content_colSwitch">
                          <span class="close_colSwitch">&times;</span>
                          <input id='1' type='checkbox' onClick='javascript:displayROW(1);' checked>Dancing Since<br>
                          <input id='2' type='checkbox' onClick='javascript:displayROW(2);' checked>D.O.B<br>
                          <input id='3' type='checkbox' onClick='javascript:displayROW(3);' checked>School<br>
                          <input id='4' type='checkbox' onClick='javascript:displayROW(4);' checked>School Code<br>
                          <input id='5' type='checkbox' onClick='javascript:displayROW(5);' checked>Teachers Name<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Column Switching ENDS -->
```

CSS

```
            /* Column Switch */

.modal_colSwitch 
{
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
.modal-content_colSwitch 
{
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #888888;
}
#myBtn_colSwitch
{
  background-color: #6599FF;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close_colSwitch {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close_colSwitch:hover,
.close_colSwitch:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Column Switch ENDS */
/* Table Style */
#myTable {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#myTable td, #myTable th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#myTable tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#myTable tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function columnSwitchMODAL()
{
    var modal_colSwitch = document.getElementById('myModal_colSwitch');
    var btn_colSwitch = document.getElementById("myBtn_colSwitch");
    var span_colSwitch = document.getElementsByClassName("close_colSwitch")[0];

    btn_colSwitch.onclick = function() 
    {
        modal_colSwitch.style.display = "block";
    }
    span_colSwitch.onclick = function() 
    {
        modal_colSwitch.style.display = "none";
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) 
    {
        if (event.target == modal_colSwitch) 
        {
            modal_colSwitch.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
function displayROW(row_no) 
{
    var hideDisplay =  '';

    if(document.getElementById(row_no).checked)
            hideDisplay = 'table-row';
    else
              hideDisplay = 'none';

    if(row_no == 1) document.getElementById('trow1').style.display = hideDisplay;
    else if(row_no == 2) document.getElementById('trow2').style.display = hideDisplay;
    else if(row_no == 3) document.getElementById('trow3').style.display = hideDisplay;
    else if(row_no == 4) document.getElementById('trow4').style.display = hideDisplay;
    else if(row_no == 5) document.getElementById('trow5').style.display = hideDisplay;

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried using the displayRow function but it is still not working. It will just refresh the page, but all rows are still showing.

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://codepen.io/badai/pen/ZjvGQe) https://codepen.io/badai/pen/ZjvGQe After clicking **Row Filter** button, a Modal will PopUp, if you toggle any checkbox that particular row will hide/display.

Comment: The codepen is not working, there is no row filter button.