# how to pass value from while loop to next page after clicking on menu item php

Tags: php, html, variables, mysqli, submenu

I have a a navigation bar and one of the nav items is a dropdown with sub categories. Only the subcategories are being pulled from the database by using a while loop.

When clicking on one of the dropdown items they will be redirected to dancerProfile.php.

I want dancerProfile.php to pull the menu item name from the other pages.

html

```
 <li class="li-spacing"><a href="parentdashboard.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown li-spacing">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dancers<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <?php
                            $dancers = "SELECT `dancer_name` FROM `dancers` WHERE name = '$name'";
                            $dres = mysqli_query($con,$dancers); 

                            //if($res==FALSE){
                            //die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
                            //  }

                            while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($dres)){
                              $dancerName = $data['dancer_name'];
                              foreach ($dancerName as $DANCER){
                                echo '
                                   <li><a href="dancerProfile.php?dancer_name=<?php echo $DANCER; ?>">'.$data["dancer_name"].'</a></li>
                                   <li class="divider"><hr></li>
                                ';
                              }
                            }
                            ?>
                            <li><a href="addDancer.php">Add New</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

This works well as all dancers appear in the dropdown. 
What I want is that when I click on dancerA the dancerProfile.php will show dancerA information. And when I click on dancerB it will show dancerB info, etc.

But it will only show the last dancer's information no matter which name I click on.

dancerProfile.php

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 dancerInfo">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="dancerName"><?php echo $dancerName;?></div>
                    </div>
```

So When I click on dancerA on the nav bar in any other page, in dancerProfile.php $dancerName should print dancerA. And it should print dancerB if I clicked on dancerB from the nav bar.

but it is only printing dancerB no matter which link I click.

I am using bootstrap. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**
Here's an update of what my code looks like now.

```
<li class="li-spacing"><a href="parentdashboard.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown li-spacing">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dancers<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <?php
                            $dancers = "SELECT `dancer_name`, `id` FROM `dancers` WHERE name = '$name'";
                            $dres = mysqli_query($con,$dancers); 
                            $dancerId= 'id';
                             }

                            while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($dres)){
                              $dancerName = $data['dancer_name'];
                                echo '
                                   <li><a href="dancerProfile.php?id=<?php echo $dancerId; ?>">'.$data["dancer_name"].'</a></li>
                                   <li class="divider"><hr></li>
                                ';
                              }
                            ?>
                            <li><a href="addDancer.php">Add New</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

And dancerProfile.php:

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
$dancerId=$_GET['id'];
$dancerquery = "SELECT `dancer_name` FROM `dancers` WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'] . ";";
                $dancer_res = mysqli_query($con,$dancers);
                if($dancer_res){
                    $DANCER='dancer_name';
                }
            }
            ?>
<div class="col-sm-6 dancerInfo">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="dancerName"><?php echo " $DANCER ";?></div>
                    </div>
```

I also forgot to mention that this navigation is also on dancerProfile page. So all of the code I am providing is on dancerProfile page. I don't know if that matters

[My database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voBDk.png)

Comment: You want yourself to get familiar with URL parameters. You should make use of [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). For clarification, when `while` loop finishes `$dancerName` holds last value of the array and that's expected.

Comment: You don't need to use the `foreach` loop, if you want to use it it must be outside of your while loop, and you need to store your results of the `while` loop in something that's interatable then loop. Otherwise you can just build the links during the `while` loop

Comment: How do I build the links during the while loop? And are you saying to that after storing loop results in a variable and the loop again? Or can I can just store loop results in a variable and then use that variable in the <li> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pass dancer id or which is unique in your dancer table. something like given below.

```
 <li><a href="dancerProfile.php?dancer_id=<?php echo $DANCER_id; ?>">'.$data["dancer_name"].'</a></li>
```

And now go to `dancerProfile.php` and try something like this.

```
if (isset($_GET['dancer_id'])) {
    $dancer_id=$_GET['dancer_id'];
    //your query
}
```

Your full code:

```
<li class="li-spacing"><a href="parentdashboard.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown li-spacing">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dancers<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php
    $dancers = "SELECT `dancer_name`, `id` FROM `dancers` WHERE name = '$name'";
    $dres = mysqli_query($con,$dancers); 
    $dancerId= 'id';
     }

    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($dres)){ ?>
      $dancerName = $data['dancer_name'];

           <li><a href="dancerProfile.php?id=<?php echo $data['id'];?>"><?php echo $data['dancer_name']; ?>'</a></li>
           <li class="divider"><hr></li>

      <?php } ?>
    <li><a href="addDancer.php">Add New</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Your `dancerProfile.php` should be

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
$dancerId=$_GET['id'];
$dancerquery = "SELECT `dancer_name` FROM `dancers` WHERE id = '$dancerId'";
    $dancer_res = mysqli_query($con,$dancerquery);
    $data=mysqli_fetch_array($dancer_res);
}
?>


<div class="col-sm-6 dancerInfo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="dancerName"><?php echo $data['dancer_name'];?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I am getting back an error Notice: Undefined variable: DANCER in /home/hqwkui898g3u/public_html/dancerProfile.php on line 362

Comment: This is the code:

<?PHP
                if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
                    $dancerId=$_GET['id'];
                    $dancer = "SELECT `dancer_name` FROM `dancers` WHERE id = '$dancerId'";
                    $dancer_res = mysqli_query($con,$dancers); 
                    $DANCER = 'dancer_name';
                }
                ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="dancerName"><?php echo $DANCER;?></div>
                        </div>

Comment: Could you show your full code with database structure

Comment: Wow, you are literally the best! I have been working on this forever, and you seriously saved me. Thanks so much for your time, patience, and help!

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: Glad to help you . enjoy coding . You can ping me if you have any problem.

Comment: Thanks, now that you mention it I do have another problem that i'm trying to figure out. If you don't mind helping me out I posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549770/how-to-hide-table-column-on-submit-inside-a-modal?noredirect=1#comment90143626_51550209

Answer (score 0):

You are currently overriding the value of `$DANCER` with each iteration, so the last will always be the used value.

Just change your loop a bit:

```
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($dres)){
     echo '<li><a href="dancerProfile.php?dancer_name='.$data['dancer_name'].'">'.$data['dancer_name'].'</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: I tried this and Ilit didn’t work. It’s still showing me the last value of my loop. :(